# java.util.Scanner is blocking me in an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I do think the problem I am having is that Scanner is blocking me in an if statement but I am not sure.

What I am trying to achieve is a program that will allow me to associate a price with a name, although that's not really relevant here. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);



        //Candies

        String red = ("red");
        String mi = ("mi");
        String name;
        String name2;

        //Prices

        double rH;
        double mNI;
        double enterP;

        //Other

        String dollar = ("$");


        //Actual Output

        System.out.println("Welcome to the store");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");

        System.out.println('\t');
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the first item: ");
        name = stdIn.nextLine();



        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase ("red") || name.equalsIgnoreCase ("redd")){

            System.out.println("Please enter price of Red:");

        }


        enterP = stdIn.nextDouble();

        if(enterP >= 0){

            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the second item:");

    }

        name2 = stdIn.nextLine();
        if(name2.equalsIgnoreCase("mi") || name2.equalsIgnoreCase("mii") || name2.equalsIgnoreCase("miii") || name2.equalsIgnoreCase("miiiii")){

            System.out.println("Enter the number of Mi to purchase:");

    }

        else if(enterP <= 0){
            System.out.println("Error: Please re-enter input");

        }
        stdIn.close();

    }
}
```

The output is kinda weird here:

[image: Works fine]

[image: Works fine]

[image: Stuck!]

I tried to close the scanner with Scanner.close(); at the end, I tried to close just the variable of the scanner with stdIn.close but nothing worked, I pretty sure I making a stupid mistake.

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your program finished execution -

For second chock and its cost again you need to read values

you need to use :
     name = stdIn.next();

instead of
      name = stdIn.nextLine();

Comment: Yesssssssssssss....Thank you so much I knew it was a stupid mistake thx

Answer (score 0):

You're not being blocked, your program has finished its execution.

By the looks of it you forgot to read the lines in for the second candy.

Answer (score 0):

you are not reading anything for the second candy.

if you look properly you just print a line to prompt second candy name but not reading it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you ever used stdIn.nextLine() after requesting for the price; try adding

```
name2 = stdIn.nextLine();
```

after

```
if(enterP >= 0){

        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the second Candy:");

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work I even tried to change the name to name2 for the second and still same problem